# Golang extension on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, extension, golang

When I am making the golang environment in visual studio, visual studio recommand a golang [extension - "goreturns"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHkJt.png)

I just pressed install, but the output tells that I had [failed to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKSpw.png)

However, I tried the same code in terminal, it is [success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOnfD.png)

But, after I had installed by terminal, when I back to my code, it still [cannot detect the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2kFA.png), even I had restarted the visual studio code.

Do any one knows that what is happening? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I asked a very stupid question. Just restart the computer is fine. I just keep it here as a reference for anyone who faced the same question as me.